# Файлы хостинга, которые отображаются в Source(F12 браузера)

Tags: файлы, консоль, хостинг, веб-сайт

### **Короче, в картинках сравнения моего сайта и взял для примера wildberries, почему у меня отображаются все файлы(в консоли разработчика F12, sources) и как сделать так, чтобы был по сути виден только индекс, ну или по минимуму файлов(как и на большинстве сайтов) как на wildberries?

### P.S. я использую бесплатный хостинг hostinger(может из-за этого?)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы раскройте у images.wbstatic.net и static.wbstatic.net

Comment: Ааа, то есть тут в любом случае, у любого сайта, будут показываться файлы, только php не будут показываться?

Comment: Видно всё что отдаётся в браузер. Просто обычно php-файлы выполняются на сервере, а в браузер отдается результат их выполнения.